# Why doesn't imshow show pixel values when I hover over it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, imshow

When I create an inline image in Ipython Notebook, it displays the image just fine. However, when I hover over the image, I cannot see the pixel values, that normally show up on the bottom right corner. How do I fix that? Thanks. (Below is some sample code).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display
%matplotlib inline  

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, figsize=(10, 10))
for ii in xrange(10):
    im = np.random.randn(100,100)
    ax.cla()
    ax.imshow(im, interpolation='None')
    ax.set_title(ii)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Inline plots are just PNG files. We cannot see coordinates when hovering over them. You must use something other than inline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the coordinates when you hover over the plot you must NOT use inline backend for the plots. So remove the `%matplotlib inline` line and restart IPython with some other backend.
You could use some other backend (it depends on what is available in your installation)
`%matplotlib gtk` or`%matplotlib qt`.

[Here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#what-is-a-backend) is an exhaustive list of supported backends. You may want to use those that are interactive instead of inline.

Comment: Thank you, may you give an example please? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was looking up the names of alternative backends. I have added them to my answer now.

Comment: Using just `%matplotlib` by itself and restarting the notebook did it for me. Thanks!